# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\wamp\www\project\uploadctrl.php on line 15

Tags: php, wamp, syntax-error, wampserver

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
       $allowed=array('image/pjepg','image/jpeg','image/JPG','image/X-PNG','image/PNG','image/png');
    if(in_array($_FILES['upload'][type],$allowed)){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],"../upload/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")){
        echo '<p><em> The file has been uploaded!</em></p>';
        }
    else {
        echo '<p class="error">Please upload a JPEG or PNG image. </p>';
    }
}
isset($_FILES['upload'])

if($_FILES['upload']['error']>0){
    echo '<p class="error">The file could not be uploaded because: <strong>';

    switch ($_FILES['upload']['error']) {
        case 1:
            print 'the file exceeds the upload_max_filesize setting in php.ini.';
            break;
        case 2:
            print 'the file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE setting in HTML form.';
            break;
        case 3:
            print 'the file was only partially uploaded.';
            break;
        case 4:
            print 'No file was uploaded.';
            break;
        case 5:
            print 'No temporary folder was availiable.';
            break;
        case 6:
            print 'Unable to write to the disk.';
            break;
        case 7: 
            print 'File uploaded stopped.';
            break;
            default:
            print 'A system error occurred.';
            break;
        }

        print '</strong></p>';
    }
  if((file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) && (is_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']))){
    unlink($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
    }
}

?>
```

when i run this i get:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\wamp\www\project\uploadctrl.php on line 15

and i cant find any errors in syntax..i search everything on code but i didnt find anything..anyone can help???

Comment: Missing `;` after `isset($_FILES['upload'])`.

Comment: You should remove `isset($_FILES['upload'])` instead of adding a semi-colon since it doesn't do anything but waste cycles on an unused conditional.

Comment: OP, your first ten lines or so really could use some indentation - it is hard for you (or anyone) to see what braces match up at the moment. Also: if you're wondering why you're getting downvotes, it's not because of the error itself - it's because you haven't explained what you've already tried to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592573/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-if) - And please learn how to debug syntax errors in PHP. Install the latest PHP 5.4 version which gives better error messages to locate causes of syntax-errors. Also an IDE like PHPStorm can help you to highlight the cause of an error while you type.

Answer (score 1):

Your:

```
isset($_FILES['upload'])
```

needs to be:

```
isset($_FILES['upload']);
```

It does say line 15, usually error lies just before that line.